# Should I use Wagtail for all models in a Django app?

Tags: django-models, wagtail

I’m in the process of building a new webapp which uses Wagtail. This is an architecture question.

There will be the standard *About*, *Terms of Service*, and *Blog* pages. All of which fit in with the Wagtail paradigm very nicely. The rest of the site content is location-based information about specific types of businesses. Think of a [FourSquare](https://foursquare.com/) type app. The data for these pages will be very structured, be updated via user-facing webpages and a mobile app, and be JavaScript heavy.

For the regular Wagtail pages, there may be hundreds over time. For the location page types there will be (hopefully) tens of thousands of pages that will be nested to a max of four levels.

From a site-wide feature perspective, I’m looking to leverage Wagtail features like sitemaps and Elastic Search.

My question is, should I use the wagtail Page class for my location based pages?

Pros:

- Easy integration with Elastic Search and Wagtail sitemaps
- Leverage Wagtail editor on the admin side.
- Consistent model and api structure throughout.

Cons:

- Potentially more overhead for location pages.
- Need to utilize more hooks to manipulate the view output (Lots of JS, so will be inserting non-model info into the template).
- Potentially limits the use of some third-party modules.

If I went the non-wagtail route, is it possible to add non-wagtail models to the search index?

Are there other issues I should consider in this choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Any Django model can be indexed and searched](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/topics/search/indexing.html#wagtailsearch-indexing-models) by inherit from `index.Indexed` and defining `search_fields` onto the model.

As for using pages or not, as always it depends on many things. However, it looks like it would make sense to keep your location model as such, not make it a page and expose in in the admin (either Django Admin if you need some extensions that already exists there, or [Wagtail's modeladmin](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/reference/contrib/modeladmin/index.html) otherwise). Then you would create a `LocationIndexPage` which implements the [RoutablePageMixin](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.13.1/reference/contrib/routablepage.html) to dynamically serve the `LocationPage`s. The page won't exists in the admin tree but will be reachable anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Loic. Hadn't thought of using Wagtail just for the index page. I'll put some thought into that.

Comment: how do we decide when to use wagtail Page and when to use Django models? Because it looks to me that, everything could be implemented in Django models, as long as we could use the wagtail edit_handlers and streamfield. So there is no reason why I should prefer wagtail Page against Django models, and this is really confusing to me as a wagtail beginner

Comment: Wagtail `Page`s should be used when you want to expose a page to the user via a URL and while being able to organise the parent/child relationship of those page via the admin interface.